# EhCache threads in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

In a simple standalone hibernate application with only one pojo using EhCache, I see the following threads:

```
Daemon Thread: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
Non Daemon Thread: com.ehcachedemo.pojos.MyPojo
```

If something is going to spawn threads, I'd like to know about. So,
what are these threads?  I can't find any more information on them?

Comment: Have you taken a thread dump yet and analysed the stack trace? Does MyPojo extend Thread / implement Runnable? Where have you taken the thread information from?

Answer (score 3):

Normally when a thread is created in Java, by default it is a non-daemon thread.
 * In HEcache each cache is a Daemon Thread.

Why Thread ??

- Entries in a cache can expire, due to age. There is a background thread running that removes expired elements; they are also removed if you try to access them.
- Each cache in your application will have a non-thread associated, that's is because the cache has operation like the one described above (expire due to age) among others.

This page show you how to [Shutting Down Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/operations/shutdown)

---

Comment: I understand Daemon Thread: net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager is there because I have configured ehcache to overflow to disk.  I do not understand why the non daemon thread corresponding to my Pojo is there.

Comment: do you have a cache for each Pojo? If is that, ehcache will create a non-daemon thread for each Pojo and that's because each cache will handle the idea of expire elements and other operations that a cache usually does.

Comment: my config is <ehcache> 
 <cache name="com.ehcachedemo.pojos.MyPojo"
   maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000"
   eternal="false"
   timeToIdleSeconds="300"
   timeToLiveSeconds="600"
   overflowToDisk="true"/> 
</ehcache>  I have only one POJO and my cache is named after it.  If I had 40 POJOs and wanted to avoid having 40 threads, how would I do that?

Comment: You need to avoid overflowToDisk="true", because that is telling to ehcache to save information on disk --> file system --> thread for 'expire due to age' operation.

Comment: You also need to setup maxElementsInMemory which is gonna be used to determinate when to write to disk.
If you want to avoid threads, remove the overflowToDisk and leave everything in memory.

Comment: And you will not have one thread for each POJO, you will have one thread for each cache region. You could reuse cache regions if the POJOs have the same cache needs